# Initial error and setup problems with Sorbet

Tags: sorbet

I'm adding Sorbet to a fairly normal mid-to-small sized Rails app.

Upon running the setup script `srb init`, I got this error confirmation:

```
Adding `typed:` sigils did not converge after 50 tries.
Would you like to continue anyway? [Y/n]
```

I selected "Y". The script then stalled for a while, reported that it was unsuccessful after 100 attempts, but then continued and said that it was "Done". It's unclear to me if this means it's working or not.

However when I run `bundle exec srb tc` there are numerous problems:

- It doesn't seem to have added any sigils, which I thought it would
- It seems to report problems in core classes:

```
https://github.com/sorbet/sorbet/tree/645cc5344236f8e32d18320dd728ea6954814229/rbi/core/class.rbi#L136: The corresponding argument arg0 in the previous definition was not a splat argument
     136 |  def instance_methods(arg0=T.unsafe(nil)); end
```

- It seems to be reporting problems in gems I don't control like activerecord:

```
sorbet/rbi/sorbet-typed/lib/activerecord/all/activerecord.rbi:464: Method ActiveRecord::Base.before_create redefined without matching argument count. Expected: 2, got: 3 https://srb.help/4010
```

Do I have to manually ignore these projects? I started doing that but I don't think that's correct either. Overall I'm unsure if the setup has worked at all, or if the initial error I received is the problem.

Version info:

```
sorbet (0.5.5384)
sorbet-runtime (0.5.5384)
sorbet-static (0.5.5384-universal-darwin-14)

rails-6.0.2.1
ruby 2.6.4p104
macOS Mojave
MacBook Pro 2017
```

Thanks

Comment: I noticed this:

`bundle exec srb tc --suggest-typed --error-white-list=7022 --typed=strict --silence-dev-message -a`

throws a seg fault:

/Users/bobwork/.rbenv/versions/2.6.4/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/sorbet-0.5.5384/bin/srb: line 46: 39783 Segmentation fault: 11  "${sorbet}" "${args[@]}"

Answer (score 0):

I believe the segfault I mentioned above was the core issue, and the error was being swallowed by the setup script.

I followed the advice [here](https://github.com/sorbet/sorbet/issues/945#issuecomment-504242089) to try and find problematic files. I noticed that Sorbet was spending a large amount of time checking Rust `.fingerprint` files in our project (embedded in our Rails app with Helix). However I couldn't reproduce a segfault. Upon removing that directory, I was able to run `srb init`! Now my setup is working as expected!